# VB.NET - Having multiple asynchronous "timeout"-type actions happening simultaneously

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm having a few issues with multi-threaded programming in VB.NET and I can't see why. In part of a program I am writing, I want dots (yellow ellipses) to appear on a panel object regularly at a set interval of xInterval milliseconds, and disappear again (be painted over with black ellipses) after being displayed for xFlashtime milliseconds. The code I have is:

```
Sub sparkles()
    ...
    'pointArray() contains the points where the dots are to appear

    For i as Integer = 0 to pointArray.Length - 1
        flashPoint(pointArray(i))
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(xInterval)
    Next i
End Sub

Async Sub flashPoint(point As Point) As Task
    *CODE TO DRAW YELLOW ELLIPSE AT point*    
    Await killPoint(point)
End Sub

Function killPoint(point As Point) As Task
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(xFlashtime)
    *CODE TO DRAW BLACK ELLIPSE AT point*
End Function
```

What I want to happen is for a new thread to run an instance of flashPoint every xInterval milliseconds, then that thread to run killPoint (which will black out the point after xFlashtime milliseconds) and die while the main thread continues through the For loop.

Should I call flashPoint(point) as a Task within the For loop? Or do I need to use Threading.Threads to create timed listeners (was hoping to avoid the hassle with an elegant "Async")?

Comment: You should use a timer that creates individual task objects for each flashpoint iteration and let a callback call killpoint.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do here. It looks like you are simply trying to create a yellow ellipse that "blinks"? Is that correct?

Comment: @user2721815 Not quite. pointArray contains random points, and every xInterval milliseconds a yellow ellipse should appear on screen, and should disappear after xFlashtime milliseconds (which could be after one or more other ellipses have appeared on screen). Have updated my question to make it clearer.